# How to show taxonomy in WordPress shortcode

Tags: themes

I want to create shortcode like [genre] for WordPress.

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_movie' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_movie() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'MOVIE', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Movie', '' ),
        "menu_name" => __( 'MOVIES LIBRARY', '' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'All Movies', '' ),
        "add_new" => __( 'Add New Movie', '' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New Movie', '' ),
        "edit" => __( 'Edit', '' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Edit Movie', '' ),
        "new_item" => __( 'New Movie', '' ),
        "view" => __( 'View', '' ),
        "view_item" => __( 'View Movie', '' ),
        "search_items" => __( 'Search Movie', '' ),
        "not_found" => __( 'No Movies found', '' ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( 'No Movies found in Trash', '' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Movie', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'MOVIE', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "All Publish Tools for Movies",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "movie", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "comments", "revisions", "thumbnail" ),     
        "taxonomies" => array( "genre", "year", "quality", "country", "awards", "type", "stars", "subtitle" ),
            );
    register_post_type( "movie", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_movie()
}
```

I want to show 'genre' in shortcode

```
function shortcode_for_genre() {
    ob_start();
    the_terms( $post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => 'genre',), '', ', ', ' ' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode ('genre', 'shortcode_for_genre');
```

I'm tried above code and few other but no one works. This shortcode show genre of post. like drama, action. etc.

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see without testing anything is that your `$post` variable is not globalized. Try transforming your `shortcode_for_genre()` fuction to something like that:

```
function shortcode_for_genre() {
    // only proceed if viewing a singular movie cpt.
    if ( ! is_singular( 'movie' ) )
        return '';

    global $post;

    ob_start();
    the_terms( $post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => 'genre',), '', ', ', ' ' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode ('genre', 'shortcode_for_genre');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a custom post type movie and a registered taxonomy to this post called genre.

The second argument of [the_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) function is wrong. It has to be a string not an array:

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ', ' ' );
```

Also you don't need to `ob_start()` and return `ob_get_clean()`. Use `get_the_terms` or `get_the_term_list` instead of `the_terms` and format the terms as you like.

```
add_shortcode ('genre', 'shortcode_for_genre');

    function shortcode_for_genre($atts){

        if ( ! is_singular( 'movie' ) ) return '';

        $html = '';            

        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genre' );

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { 

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                $link = get_term_link( $term, 'genre' );

               if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
                   return '';
               }

               $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';

            }


        }

        return $html;

    }
```

or

```
add_shortcode ('genre', 'shortcode_for_genre');

function shortcode_for_genre($atts){

            if ( ! is_singular( 'movie' ) ) return '';

           return get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'genre', '', ', ', '');

        }
```